# Bar chart Plot a dataframe with three columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following data for dataframe:

```
data = [{'City': 'SF', 'Tools':'Subways', 'Numbers':10}, {'City': 'SF', 'Tools':'Foot', 'Numbers':4}, {'City': 'SF', 'Tools':'Bike', 'Numbers':8}, {'City': 'SF', 'Tools':'Skateboard', 'Numbers':2}, {'City': 'SF', 'Tools':'Ferry', 'Numbers':3}, {'City': 'Seattle', 'Tools':'Car', 'Numbers':15}, {'City': 'Seattle', 'Tools':'Train', 'Numbers':5}, {'City': 'Seattle', 'Tools':'Ferry', 'Numbers':9}, {'City': 'Seattle', 'Tools':'Bike', 'Numbers':9}, {'City': 'Boston', 'Tools':'Subway', 'Numbers':10}, {'City': 'Boston', 'Tools':'Car', 'Numbers':10}, {'City': 'Shanghai', 'Tools':'Car', 'Numbers':4}, {'City': 'Shanghai', 'Tools':'Subway', 'Numbers':20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to plot it like the following

[image: bar chart with different categories]

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot the table and plot:

```
ax = df.pivot(index='City', columns='Tools', 
              values='Numbers').plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.set_ylabel('Numbers')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]